# Call to a possibly undefined method makelvl 1180

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm making a brick breaker game but keep getting 1180 error. I can't find the problem. Any ideas?

```
function checkLevel(event:Event):void{
    if(brickAmt == 0)
    {
        currentLvl ++;
        makeLvl();
        MrBall.x = 150;
        MrBall.y = 265;
        MrPaddle.x = 230;
        MrPaddle.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movePaddle);
        MrBall.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBall);
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkLevel);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, beginCode);
    }
}
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, beginCode);
makeLvl();
```

Comment: Where is your `makeLvl()` method code located relevant to this code?

Comment: Looks like you copied this code from somewhere and did not got all of it. Where is the make makeLvl() method defined.